# The destination google bucket --- does not exist or the write to the destination must be restarted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket

I have a static website which sat in a google cloud bucket. It is up and running but I need to make updates. In my google cloud console, the buckets I would think they might be all look empty. I put these commands in the readme:

```
gsutil -m cp -r * gs://www.site.com

gsutil -m rsync -r -d . gs://www.site.com
```

When I run the first one, I get this error:

> The destination bucket gs://www.site.com does not exist or the write to the destination must be restarted

When I run the second, I get:

> BucketNotFoundException: 404 gs://www.site.com bucket does not exist.

I can't imagine what project or subscription the bucket is in other than the one that these names:

> site.appspot.com
> staging.site.appspot.com
> us.artifacts.site.appspot.com

But they are all empty. I am wondering how I could find either from the static site or DNS config which bucket I should be looking at. Also wondering if there has been any update in the past year or two that is making these buckets look empty while the site is still live.